# If I try to call multiple methods from django views sequentially with ajax, only the last call's response is returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

Hi everyone,

I am building a web application in django, that takes a file from the user, processes it server side, zips the results and downloads the zip file to the user.
The downloading part is done with an ajax call from a template. After downloading the file, I would like to delete it from the server, so I made a method called clean_up, that wipes all folders.

**Ajax call from the template:** 
(I tried other things too, like calling window.location in the complete() part with no success. If I only run the first ajax call, that works, the two together do not, but the logger.debug prints the messages in my command line, so I know the methods are called and run, just the response is not returned)

```
function my_download() {
   $.ajax({
                url: '/ymap_webtool/result',
                type: "GET",
                data: {  },
                success: function (data) { 
                alert("The browser is now going to download the results")
                window.location = '/ymap_webtool/result';
                },
                complete: function () { },
                error: function () { }
        }).then($.ajax({
                url: '/ymap_webtool/clean_up',
                type: "GET",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/ymap_webtool/clean_up';
                },
                complete: function () { },
                error: function () { 
                window.location.href = '/ymap_webtool/submission_failed';
                }
            }));
    };
```

**Called methods from the views:**

```
def download_result(request):
    #download the results to the user
    resp_file = open(os.path.join(archive_path, archive_name + ".zip"), 'rb') #the rb flag is needed on windows!motherwise r should be sufficient
    response = HttpResponse(resp_file, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % download_name
    logger.debug("download the zip file")
    return response    

def clean_up(request):
    #erase the input, output, but keep the archive under another name
    #wipe_folder(input_path)
    #wipe_folder(output_path)
    logger.debug("hello from cleanup")
```

I want my user to be able to download the file, and once this has happened, delete all input and output on the server side. (maybe archive the results)

When I call ONLY the download_result method with ajax, the file downloads. But when I try to call the download_result and the clean_up subsequetly, django does not download the file. The method runs, judging by the logger.debug command line prints, but the response is not returned. Also django errors out that the clean_up method does not return a HttpResonse object.

Comment: Yes, because you change the window location in each success call, interrupting the script. Why do you do that?

Comment: And yes, the clean_up method does not return a response, which it must do; why is that confusing?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to both django and java script, I understand it might be a silly question. 
But if I don't change the window location, the file would not download. Why must the clean_up method return a response?

Comment: Because that is required by Django. The contract for a view is that it accepts a request and returns a response - which must be an instance of HttpResponse, although it can be an empty one.

Comment: Then should I just put void functions in an other pydev module? I am not sure how could I call for the clean_up on the server side or on the client side in that case

Comment: I don't understand any of that comment. What "void function"? What "other pydev module"? You can call clean_up via Ajax, as you are doing. But none of this has anything to do with the original problem, which as I stated originally is caused by you changing the URL in the middle of the Ajax callbacks. Don't do that.

Comment: So you mean just erase the window.location from the success part?

Comment: By void function I meant a function that does not return anything